# If a differentiable function has bounded derivative, Must it be that its derivative continuous?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

I got this question:

Let $f$ be a continuous function on the closed interval $[a,b]$ and differentiable on the open interval $(a,b)$, If $f'$ is bounded on $(a,b)$, Must it be the case that $f'$ is continuous on $(a,b)$?

Thanks.

Comment: Try something like $x^2 \sin(1/x)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x^2 \sin \frac{1}{x} &\hbox{for $x \neq 0$}\\
0 &\hbox{for $x=0$}
\end{cases}
$$
on the inteval $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Nice counter example. Thanks.